# Best content type to serve JSONP?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I have a webservice that when called without specifying a callback will return a JSON string using `application/json` as the content type.

When a callback is specified it will wrap the JSON string in a callback function, so it's not really valid JSON anymore. My question is, should I serve it as `application/javascript` in this case or still use `application/json`?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use application/javascript. In that way, clients can rely on the content-type without having to manually check whether a response has padding or not.

Comment: It fails in IE 9 with message "SEC7112: Script from http://xyz.com was blocked due to mime type mismatch " Any idea why ?

Comment: Content type "application/javascript" may mismatch with "text/javascript" that specified in script tag (or expected by default for some reason)

Comment: Based on the information in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/26/mime-handling-changes-in-internet-explorer.aspx) text/javascript and application/javascript would work in IE 9. I wonder @pit-digger if the server just wasn't returning the correct content-type header.

Answer (score 122):

Use `application/json` [as per rfc4627.txt](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) if what you return is plain JSON.

If you return JavaScript (which is really what JSONP is), then use `application/javascript` [as per rfc4329.txt](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt)