# C# Adding callback to JsonResult

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

My mvc page returns json by using the function Json(mycustomclass) to return a JsonResult object.

This works just fine except, I need to wrap the json in a callback so that jQuery can use it.

I want it like this:
jsonp1246168411282({"myjson":"some values"})

but I am getting this:
{"myjson":"some values"}

Is there any way I can 'wrap' the C# JsonResult with brackets and the jquery callback?

Thanks

The Lorax

Comment: For anyone else that needs a solution to this and doesn't want to use a WCF Service check this link out : http://stimms.blogspot.com/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-returning-jsonp.html

Comment: or alternatively you can do this:
              string json_string = (callback + "(" + new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(json) + ")");
                JavaScriptResult result = new JavaScriptResult();
                result.Script = json_string;
                return result;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery can use the json response just fine unless you are calling this action from a page in another domain. Is this what you are doing? 
If so I advise you to create a wcf service which supports jsonp. Example [here](http://jasonkelly.net/archive/2009/02/24/using-jquery-amp-jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax-with-wcf-services.aspx)

If not you can just use the [getJson](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) jquery method.

Comment: Hi redsquare. Yes, my service needs to be accessible from other domains. Currently I have I view page that returns the json but I am working on a better solution that allows me to serialize a large custom class into json and return it as an object. 

I might just use an open source json serializer to turn it into a string and return it as a string.

Thanks for your help thought.
Best Regards,
The Lorax

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.net MVC returning JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758879/asp-net-mvc-returning-jsonp)

Also, something like:

```
public JavaScriptResult Test()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string callback = Request.Params["callback"] + "(" + javaScriptSerializer.Serialize("testing, testing") + ");";
    return JavaScript(callback);
}
```