# Why do I get a 403 forbidden when calling to external IIS based MVC controller returning a JSON result

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have an application that's been provided by a third party.  The only means of modifying the behavior is through client side script.  I have a screen in the app that does some ad-hoc querying but doesn't provide any means by which to save the settings.  Rather than have the user re-enter setting each time, I've injected some elements via jQuery to enable them to save their queries.

I have another internal site that is asp.net MVC that I've added a controller with a method GetQueryList(string User).

From the browser everything work fine, I get my result returned, but from script I get a 403.  I've been chasing my tale for two days on this now.

I dumbed down the methods to just get things working.

Here's the controller code:

```
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)> _ 
Public Function GetQueryList(ByVal user as String) as JsonResult   
    Return Me.Json(String.format("Hello {0}", user))
End Function
```

Client code:

```
    $.getJSON("http://myservername.org/ClientQuery.mvc/GetQueryList",
        null
        , function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    );
```

If anyone has any ideas it might save what little hair I have left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because browsers implement a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that blocks AJAX requests to other domains.

You can create a local AJAX class to proxy the external AJAX request on behalf of the user, using a .NET [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx?PHPSESSID=lm71lj7i6gj5fjtebtb2srl4n3).  Note that WebRequest has no constructor and uses a factory method `WebRequest.create(Uri)` instead.

Comment: This is what I feared.  Question becomes now how to implement the proxy when I don't have access to the the application code? Again the only modifications I'm able to make in the applications are client side behavoirs via javascript.

Comment: You get the the check because I believe you answered the question I had initially which was why.  Your answer confirmed my suspicion and eventually led me to the as described here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758879/asp-net-mvc-returning-jsonp

Comment: I feel stupid now.  I didn't even think of JSONP, which is JSON with a Javascript callback on the caller, that nicely averts the need for a proxy.