# Consume wcf jsonp services using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, cross-domain, jsonp

How can I consume CrossDomaine services from my code behind using jsonp data.

I did it with javascript and it works just fine.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    timeout: 10000,
    url: getUrl() + "ExecuteAction?callback=?",
    data: { action: "HelloWorld", args: 'test'},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp"
}).done(function (msg) {alert("success");}).fail(function () {alert("error");});
```

Thanks.

Comment: The previous question also is posted by @Nabila  :), but this question  is concentrating on the JSONP specifically and this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758879/asp-net-mvc-returning-jsonp

Comment: @LearningNeverStops there is noting related to jsonp other than his title. I think OP is misguided by the answer in his previous question.

Comment: @L.B correct, I concluded about JSONP by looking at the last comment in that question and the title of this question. So now the user is stuck with jsonp code behind.

Comment: Thanks @LearningNeverStops I am in fact stuck with jsonp code behind