# JSONP response http content-type header

Tags: http, jsonp

What should the value of content-type http header be if the message body is JSONP. application/javascript?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111302/best-content-type-to-serve-jsonp

Comment: @tomlogic Thanks! Somehow I was not able to find that question using the search feature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depends on the body's **actual** content. That's what the `Content-Type` header stands for.

So, if you write a JS callback function to the body, then yes, it should be `application/javascript`.

Or, if you write a JSON string to the body, then no, it should be `application/json` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ajax to work for the case in which you have a file upload field in a form as part of the input, and you aren't using XHR2, it must be 'text' or 'text/html' and you need to surround it with a fake HTML element. See the jquery forms ajax support doc for all the nasty details.

Comment: _"you need to surround it with a fake HTML element"_ - That isn't true, I've done Ajax in FF with JSON (no html).