# Consume JSON in body of POST Request from ASP.NET

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to be able to consume some JSON data in a POST request from another web app. I have tried looking at the various methods on the Request class, but nothing seems to give me the JSON I need.

Using `Request.Form` will not work, since it is not coming from a form, but another web app. The content type is `application/json`, and from examining the whole HTTP request, I know the JSON is in there. What is the best way to get at this JSON data?

Note: I am working from within an action on a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get your JSON from your model parameter inside the Action of the Controller. Check out this [article](http://lozanotek.com/blog/archive/2010/04/16/posting_json_data_to_mvc_controllers.aspx) that explains a bit of what I mean.

You can also read this [one](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) for reference

Answer (score 1):

Since you are consuming data from another web app I would use a REST web service instead of a controller in an MVC application.  You cans use the [ASP.NET Web API](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/02/16/asp-net-4-beta-released.aspx) which makes it easy to setup a REST web API and it is tightly integrated in with MVC 4, which is now in Beta. If the communication is cross domain (i.e. different servers and/or ports) you will need to use JSONP. You can go to this [StackOverflow QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421312/jsonp-with-mvc-4-webapi) for directions on how to use JSONP with Web API.