# How do I handle JSONP with WebAPI?

Tags: jsonp, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSONP with MVC 4 WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421312/jsonp-with-mvc-4-webapi)

I have a get method for my WebAPI which is as follows:

```
    private T Get<T>(string uri)
    {
        T result = default(T);
        bool isSuccess = true;

        client
            .GetAsync(uri)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                // EnsureStatus
                isSuccess = task.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
                task
                .Result
                .Content
                .ReadAsAsync<T>()
                .ContinueWith(t => result = t.Result)
                .Wait();
            })
            .Wait();
       return result;
     }
```

The result is produced in a JSON format but I want it for JSONP.

I have read that `ReadAsSync` only handles built in mediaformatters. So is there a way I can change it to handle JsonP?

Comment: Why would you need JSONP on a .NET client?

Comment: Quite often JSONP is used to pull data across domains.

Comment: @EBarr yes, in javascript and in browser. Not when you have a full-blown .NET client. The server must be able to serve json if client asks for `application/json`. This is a **content negotiation** issue.

Comment: @EBarr - You are right! I do not have a full-blown .NET client. So it is a content negotiation issue. Adding an extra method to handle Jsonp could be helpful. I read about JsonpMediaTypeFormatter and it should be added to  the Application_Start of global.asax. But we are not using a global.asax to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stealing liberally from [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421312/jsonp-with-mvc-4-webapi)....

To accomplish what you want you need three things :

1. to add a `media formatter` that outputs JSONP
2. register the media formatter (traditionally done through global.asx)
3. ensure the client requests jsonP.

You can steal this  JSONP media [formatter](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.Web.Http/blob/master/Thinktecture.Web.Http/Formatters/JsonpFormatter.cs).

Then, you need to register the media formatter. You can do this programatically with the following code snippet:

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Since you apparently don't use global.asax you're going to need to make sure the formatter is registered somehow.  YOU don't provide enough information on how to do it, but i suspect a judiciously placed IF statement and a static variable indicating registration would get you there.

I still don't quite know what type of client you're using, but if it's jquery something like the following will get you there:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://myurl.com',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.MyProperty);
    }
})
```

The important part is the `accept` header sent matches the accept header your shiny new jsonp formatter is listening for.  The top two choices in my opinion are either: `application/javascript` or `text/javascript`.

Comment: Its a selfhosting server so we have something like:

var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:1234");
server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);

Comment: I haven't worked with the self hosted stuff yet, but i suspect you need to add some properties to that `config` object you're passing in to `HttpSelfHostServer`

Comment: Agreed. And It should be something like:
config.Formatters[0] = new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter();

However this is not the case. HttpSelfHostConfiguration derives from HttpConfiguration that doesnt have the set property for Formatter.
Thank you!

Comment: Ok. Got it all working! Thanks for your help! I was missing the System.Net.Http.Formatting dll because of which I could not add JsonpMediaTypeFormatter to the config.

Comment: The JsonP media formatter is now part of WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp in NuGet.