# WebApi - Data returns as XML when I request it as JSONP

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jsonp, asp.net-web-api

In my Web Api project I have a Get method which returns data from my datasource:

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
    public IQueryable<Product> Get()
    {
        var products = _db.Products;
        return products.AsQueryable();
    }
```

When I view this in the browser with the test client, when I specify to return as JSON it works fine and JSON is returned.

On my other client, I have to make a JSONP due to my API being hosted on same domain (For development only), but the data I receive back from my JSON request is XML, how can I make it return as JSON? Below is my code to make the request:

```
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://localhost:9000/api/products",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: "get",
        success: function (data) {

            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you are still using the now obsolete WCF Web API rather than the newer ASP.NET Web API.  See http://nuget.org/packages/AspNetWebApi

Comment: @DarrelMiller - good catch. I didn't even notice the `WebGet` attribute.

Comment: I've since swapped it to use ASP.NET Web API and used `EBarr`'s answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stealing liberally from [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421312/jsonp-with-mvc-4-webapi)....

Your primary issue is that there is no JSONP media formatter registered in webapi by default.To accomplish what you want you need three things :

1. to add a `media formatter` that outputs JSONP
2. register the media formatter
3. ensure the client requests jsonP.

You can steal this  JSONP media [formatter](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.Web.Http/blob/master/Thinktecture.Web.Http/Formatters/JsonpFormatter.cs).

Then, you need to register the media formatter. You can do this programatically with the following code snippet:

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Generally you do this in `Application_Start()` in `global.asax`.

Your query looks like it's requesting JSONP just fine. Once the above is accomplished it should work.  The important part is the `accept` header sent matches the accept header your shiny new jsonp formatter is listening for.  The top two choices in my opinion are either: `application/javascript` (like you're requesting) or `text/javascript`.