# $.ajax() on phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, github

Anyone know an example of *phonegap* with `$.ajax()` in *github* for Android? I have read of JSONP or CORS but I have worked only requesting data from Twitter.

I just need to get my data server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy through jquery mobile. You can do your job with normal Ajax and little bit of JSON. I done with php server. Here the sample code,

Sending request to server through jquery.

```
$.ajax({
          url: <your Server URL>,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
          timeout: 5000,
          success: function(data, status){
                             /*Process your response here*/
                        }
       });
```

In php server file,

```
<?php
$data="I am sending response to you";

/*you have to mention this callback compulsory*/

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($data) . ');';
?>
```

Comment: can you give me any advise about how to do this with asp.net mvc3?

Comment: hi, just go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421312/jsonp-with-asp-net-web-api.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [URL](http://samcroft.co.uk/2010/loading-data-into-a-phonegap-app/). It will help you to load data from your data server.

Comment: thanks, but I only worked with Twitter, I need any special type of output in the server response?

Comment: @fdbazan: No. It depends on type of output you want.