# Ajax call never gets called in phonegap for android

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I searched similar questions but never found a proper answer. I am making app for multiple platforms using phonegap and JQM. I made index.html, which is "login page", with similar call. Index's call works, but the one below never gets called on my android device, even though it works both on chrome and safari.

I checked sever logs and there are no problems with "login", but as I said, there is no request from my android device when function below should be called.

```
    //document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true; 
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        console.log('Page Started');
})

//var onDeviceReady = function(){

$( document ).ready(function (){
        console.log('Start');
        //$.support.cors = true;
        //$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        $.ajax({                                                                   
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://ip/services/rest/contact/list', 
        callback: 'jsonpCallback',
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
        jsonp: '_jsonp',
        contentType:  'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp json',
        timeout : 10000,

        success: function(data){

            var html ='';
            console.log('Success');
            $.each(data.response, function(key, value) {
            html += '<li><a class=contact href="#" id="' + data.response[key].id + '" ><h1>' + data.response[key].label + '</h1><p>'+ data.response[key].customerName + '</p><p>' + data.response[key].phone + ', ' + data.response[key].email + '</p></a></li>';
            $('#ul_id').append($(html));
            html='';
            console.log('conatct');
            });
            $('#ul_id').trigger('create');    
            $('#ul_id').listview('refresh');

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert("Status: " + xhr.status + ", Ajax option: " + ajaxOptions + ", Thrown error: " + thrownError);
            //location.reload();
            console.log('Blad');
        },
    }); 
});
```

Comment: please provide the server source code also

Comment: Server side works well. I simplz have no reqests from mobile.

Comment: Read my old post. You ll get a clue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054319/ajax-on-phonegap/11062464#11062464

Comment: Sorry, I havent found the answer. Could you be more specific? T tried the same ajax calls in two html files. The first-site ajax calls properly, second-linked-site ajax  never gets called. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with placing script and specific way that jqm work.

Comment: What was the problem/fix if you don't mind me asking? (For future stackoverflowers).

Answer (score 0):

What is the access origin value in your Android project config.xml file ?

your value should be as below :

```
<access origin=".*"/>
```

Comment: I think you mean ``<access origin="*"/>``
[Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide)