# Calling MVC4 Web API from a Normal HTML File outside the project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have trying to learn MVC4 Web API. I am running my project from VS2010 itself.

My project URL is localhost:31735

When directly calling the WebAPI from browser itself. It works like localhost:31735/api/products/

I now want to invoke the Webapi from a normal HTML file outside the project.

I tried to do this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
           // Send an AJAX request 
            $.getJSON("http://localhost:31735/api/products/",
            function (data) {
            // On success, 'data' contains a list of products. 
               $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                // Format the text to display. 
                var str = val.Name + ': $' + val.Price;

                // Add a list item for the product. 
                $('<li/>', { html: str }).appendTo($('#products'));
            });
        });
    });
```

But this doesnot work. Can you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I now want to invoke the Webapi from a normal HTML file outside the project.

You can't do this because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction which prevents you from sending cross domain AJAX requests. There are [different possible workarounds](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide), one of which consists into using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) instead of JSON.

Here's [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422178/29407) which describes how to achieve that by using a custom media formatter.