# Using Ajax/jsonp to receive data from Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I've built a simple web service using the Web Api and I want to consume it from a simple mVC view using jQuery. I'm developing on localhost and consuming the service from Azure, which is why I'm using jsonp.

When I run my jQuery I view in Fiddler and the request is successful and json sent back but the .Ajax function returns these errors:

NaN, parsererror, and callback was not called

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        var callback = function(data) {
            alert(data);
        };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://itjobsdirect.azurewebsites.net/api/values/getbytitle?title=developer',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#main').text(data);

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                    alert(jqXHR.status + jqXHR.message);
                    alert(textStatus);
                    alert(error);
                }
            });



    });
</script>
```

I found this question: [JsonP with Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421312/jsonp-with-asp-net-web-api) is it still relevant?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the link to that question you have there is still relevant.

ASP.NET Webapi doesn't ship with a default formatter that understands the dataType of 'jsonp' and so the solution here is to add a custom JsonpMediaTypeFormatter (as shown in the answer for the questions you have linked).

Comment: Used revealing modules in the end with Handlebars templates