# jquery ajax call to .NET web api returns error

Tags: c#, jquery, callback, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I have a simple ApiController I'm testing:

```
namespace SMOnline.Controllers
{
    public class DocumentosController : ApiController
    {
        Documentos[] docs = new Documentos[] 
        { 
            new Documentos { ID = 1, Tipo = 1, Designacao = "FC001"}, 
            new Documentos { ID = 2, Tipo = 1, Designacao = "FC002"}
        };

        public IEnumerable<Documentos> GetAll()
        {
            return docs;
        }
    }
}
```

And on the client side i'm calling this from a different domain

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: 'GET', //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: apiUrl + 'Documentos/', // Location of the service
    dataType: 'jsonp', //Expected data format from server
})
.done(function (data) {
    // On success, 'data' contains a list of documents.
    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
       alert(item.Designacao);
    })
})
.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    alert(textStatus + " " + error);
});
```

My problem is that the JSONP request is allways returning me an error

> parsererror Error: jQuery20301899278084596997_1380125445432 was not called

I've been searching arround but still haven't found a solution for this.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that using fiddler the returned values seem correct header is 200 and the content is a JSON array.

Comment: jsonp should be treated at the server side . where in the server side you do something like this :  `return "myCallBack("+data+");"` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir is there anyway that i can know what's the automatic callback value created in the server side?

Comment: @RoyiNamir wasn't able to use it but i found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by creating an ActionFilterAttribute. I found the solution in the answer from 010227leo on this thread [JSONP with ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421312/jsonp-with-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp) to handle correctly your JSONP call.

On package manager console:

```
Install-Package WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use different output formats in web api, you have to register appropriate Formatters in `FormatterConfig` . 
Also add `contentType: "application/json"` to your ajax call.
More in detail explanation can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631685/JSONP-in-ASP-NET-Web-API-Quick-Get-Started#pre0)