# Jquery getJson method is not working while requesting from ASP webApi

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I've been trying to get data from my ASP WebApi but it is not showing any results, it always fails.

my ASP project is already published on a hosting server, im using the link from my mobile device(Windows Phone) to request data and its working very good.
but when I try to use Jquery from my PC (Not in the same project)

it returns nothing.

this is my controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
 public JsonResult GetTestData()
    {
        string[] arr = { "val1", "val2", "val3" };
        return new JsonResult() { Data = arr, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

and my Jquery function

```
$("button").click(function(){
$.getJSON("http://myurl.com/api/GetTestData",function(result){
 $.each(result, function(i, field){
   $("div").append(field + " ");
  });
 });
});
```

I've been searching and found nothing

some people used Json(arr), and I cant find the Json class

Im new to ASP MVC.

Comment: are you doing a cross-domain request?

Comment: `some people used Json(arr)`, `Json` is a method, not a class. Calling it creates a `JsonResult`.

Comment: In case you're doing a cross domain request. You could try JSONP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421312/jsonp-with-asp-net-web-api or enabling CORS: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$.each(result.d, function(i, field)`

Comment: Its working on fiddlr ! 
but not from jquery !