# Using fiddler to test my WEB Api . Which content type to select and the input parameter is always null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I created a Web API which accepts Json string and returns an XML.
I am trying to test my web API using fiddler and unable to test it.

My get method in code:

```
[HttpGet]        
        public XmlDocument GetXML([FromBody]string JsonString)
        { 
            System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDocument = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(JsonString);
```

In fiddler :When I provide the content type as application json(below is screen shot). It throws a HTTP 500 error.
    "An error has occurred.No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String' from content with media type 'application/json'."

But when I provide the content-Type :application/xml. It successfully makes a connection to the web api but the Input parameter "JsonString" is null.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot though it looks like you ARE in fact passing a string because it start with an equals and quotes like `="{ ... }"`. This looks like a JSONP body. JSON would look start with curl braces like `{ ... }`

If you need to accept JSONP have a look at this answer:
[JSONP with ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421312/jsonp-with-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: Oliver, I am trying to send a Json String. The client application who will be using my API will be passing the Json data in a String.