# How to set content type dynamically in a Spring MVC controller (depending on presence of request param)?

Tags: spring-mvc, http-headers, content-type

I have a REST API that until now always returned JSONP (JSON data wrapped in whatever function call client wanted):

```
static final String JAVASCRIPT = "application/javascript;charset=UTF-8"; 

@RequestMapping(value = "/matches", produces = JAVASCRIPT)
@ResponseBody
public String matches(@RequestParam String callback) {
    String json = jsonService.getCachedJson("/matches");
    return toJsonp(callback, json);
}
```

Now, things have changed so that I need to return **either JSON or JSONP**: if client provides a callback function name, we return JSONP and otherwise pure JSON.

With regards to content type, I'd like to be as correct as possible and [use `application/json` for JSON and `application/javascript` for JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111319/56285).

So, something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/matches")
@ResponseBody
public String matches(@RequestParam(required = false) String callback) {
    String json = jsonService.getCachedJson("/matches");

    // TODO: if callback == null, set content type to "application/json", 
    // otherwise to "application/javascript"

    return jsonOrJsonp(callback, json);
}

String jsonOrJsonp(String callback, String json) {
    return Strings.isNullOrEmpty(callback) ? json : toJsonP(callback, json);
}
```

Looks like I can no longer use `produces` attribute of `@RequestMapping`. What's the **simplest** way to set content type with Spring MVC in the scenario above?

I'd like to avoid defining HttpMessageConverters (or other Spring hassle) or changing the method return type, if at all possible! And obviously I wouldn't like duplicated method declarations where `produces` value is the only significant difference. What I'm looking for is *minimal changes* to the above code.

Latest Spring (3.2.3).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just using two request handler methods?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/matches", produces = JAVASCRIPT, params="callback")
@ResponseBody
public String Jsonp(@RequestParam String callback) {
    return toJsonp(callback, jsonService.getCachedJson("/matches"));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/matches", produces = JSON)
@ResponseBody
public String json() {
    return toJson(jsonService.getCachedJson("/matches"));
}
```

The first method with the `params` parameter will only be mapped to requests where the `callback` param is present.

Comment: Sure, that's possible, but not very elegant. As I wrote in the question: "And obviously I wouldn't like duplicated method declarations where `produces` value is the only significant difference."

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your post well enough. Check out [this post](http://www.iceycake.com/2012/06/xml-json-jsonp-web-service-endpoints-spring-3-1/) and [this post](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/#comment-171228). Hope those are more helpful.