# Jsonp callback issue: input text is undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

According to same origin policy, I can't use regular json for ajax call, so I use jsonp instead.
I have a simple input field and class name is "newCaller".
In my js file

```
$(document).on("blur", ".newCaller", function(){
  var name = $(this).val();
  var tel = $(this).siblings(".tel").text();
  //console.log(name+tel);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'xxx.xxx.com/phpFunc.php',
    data: ({ 'name' : name, 'tel' : tel }),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    //I tried success instead of jsonpCallback as well
    jsonpCallback: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

And here is the php:

```
<?php
 $name = $_GET['name'];
 $tel = $_GET['tel'];
 echo $name.$tel;
?>
```

When the ajax function is triggered, the value from the field is undefined. For example, I type "test" into text field and trigger the function, please see following image (sorry for the black line, privacy policy)
[image]

I use success to callback and returns almost the same thing, "xxx is not defined".
Could someone tell me how to fixed it? Thank!

Comment: Check the JSON syntax. What you return from your PHP file is not JSON.

Comment: ur not converting the values to json in php page.u need to give   $arr=array($name=>$tel);json_encode($arr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues are mostly server-side as that script isn't quite enough to support [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

1. It has to [output valid JSON](http://php.net/json_encode):

   ```php
   json_encode($name . $tel);
   ```
2. And include the padding (the `callback`):

   ```php
   echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($name . $tel) . ');';
   ```

And, you'll want to change `jsonCallback` back to `success`.

Comment: Great! this works! u r my hero! I got "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:". What does this mean?

Comment: @nich Ah. You'll have to specify the `Content-Type`: [`header('Content-type: application/javascript');`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/111306). Add that before the `echo`.

Comment: Thanks again, may I ask you one more question. How can I extract the $tel and $name back to my js. In the end of my php, I do echo $name and $tel. I tried $name=$_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($name) . ');'; and $tel=$_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($name) . ');';. but it won't work. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: @nich You'll have to output them grouped together in one JSON value: `json_encode(array($name, $tel))` with `data[0]` and `data[1]`. Associative arrays work as well, but encode as `Object`s in JSON: `array("name" => $name, "tel" => $tel)` with `data.name` and `data.tel`.

Answer (score 0):

ur not converting the values to json in php page phpFunc.php.u need to give

```
$arr=array($name=>$tel);
json_encode($arr);
```

because ur doing it in json format..so u need to get data in json format only.but ur sending in normal text format soit shows mime/type error

to check exact error try this

```
$(document).on("blur", ".newCaller", function(){
 var name = $(this).val();
 var tel = $(this).siblings(".tel").text();
  //console.log(name+tel);
   $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
   url: 'xxx.xxx.com/phpFunc.php',
   data: ({ 'name' : name, 'tel' : tel }),
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
    //alert(xhr.responseText);
      return false;
         },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  //I tried success instead of jsonpCallback as well
  success: function(data){
   console.log(data);
 }
 });
```

});

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added this two lines into my code. and then I do "echo $arr;". And I rerun my code, but still get "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:". What have I done wrong?

Comment: ru doing json encode in phpFunc.php page and also make jsonpCallback to success